# Custom iOS Popover for Print Options

Tags: ios, printing

I am trying to create a multi-language Application where I can print a document.

When Print button is pressed it shows a standard iOS popover with print options.
But its in English and not in the language of the device

I Localized Strings for my application. Also the other parts are working fine. But I am not able to find the exact place where set the labels in the Print Options.

This is what I used to call the popover for Print Options

```
[printController presentFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:animated completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

What would be the method to convert the labels on this popover to custom language i.e. Device language.

An example on the same will really be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go through Apple's Localisation/Internationalisation guide for multilanguage support. 
 https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/

The way for you is to use NSLocalizedString in place of NSStrings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Localize your application.

1. Create `.strings` files for the supported languages
2. Add the localized string as a key value pair in the `.strings` file
3. Use the key to retrieve the supported language string (Device language)

You can use this code for retrieving the localized string:

```
NSString *localizedString = NSLocalizedString(@"key", @"");
```

#### Tutorials:

1. [Localize iOS app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial)
2. [NSLocalized String](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-localization-with-nslocalizedstring/)

Comment: I do have Localized Strings with application. Also the other parts are working fine. But I am not able to find the exact place where i can use the function you mentioned for the labels in the Print Options.

Comment: that will surely work. But how do access the labels there as it is iOS standard view and not in the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the language in the application's main method. Look at this answer [Using different language for system views than the current device language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404365/using-different-language-for-system-views-than-the-current-device-language)